# auto resume from standby

Tags: linux, hibernate, scheduled-tasks, wake-up, standby

Can a Ubuntu (or any other distro) wake up from standby/hibernate at a preset time?

I actually don't want the PC to consume 200W all the time for just doing something every hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`rtcwake`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rtcwake) is a standard Linux command that enters a standby or sleep state until the specified time. It depends on BIOS support; most current PCs do support it. You can specify either a sleep duration (in seconds) or a wake up date (in seconds since the epoch, as produced by `date +%s`).

```
rtcwake -s 3600
rtcwake -t $(date +%s 'now + 1 hour')
```

Comment: I tried on my compaq and it never even went to speed after the command. My Asus/AMD desktop did go to sleep instantly using " -s 60" but never woke up.